# log4net Print ordered logs on another file

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, log4net, log4net-appender

In my software there is a *logger* object (log4net) that regularly do its job: prints a log file into a folder.
However, since multiple threads are executed simultaneously (multithreading executed through multiple tasks), I get a very confusing log file.
I would like, without making too many changes to the code already written, to have *a second log file* that this time follows my logic before it is printed.

Until now, I was able to intercept the log4net logging events, and I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to solve my problem.

This is an example class where I use a normal logger:

```
class Core
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name); // my default logger

    private static MyLogger myLogger = MyLogger.GetLogger(Thread.CurrentThread, logger); // my interceptor

    public void ExecuteGenericMethodCommand(Metodo metodo)
    {
        logger.Info("First comment");
        // ... stuff...
        logger.Info("Second comment");
    }
}
```

Here the implementation of a *interceptor* of the logger,  with an appender:

```
internal class MyLogger 
{
    static MyLogger myLogger;
    static Thread CurrentThread;
    static Logger InterceptedLogger;
    static MessageModifyingForwardingAppender newAppender = new MessageModifyingForwardingAppender();

    private MyLogger()
    {
        myLogger = new MyLogger();
    }

    internal static MyLogger GetLogger(Thread currentThread, ILog logger)
    {
        CurrentThread = currentThread;
        InterceptedLogger = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)logger.Logger;
        InterceptedLogger.AddAppender(newAppender);
        return myLogger;
    }


    class MessageModifyingForwardingAppender : ForwardingAppender
    {
        private static Queue<LoggingEvent> Queue;

        public MessageModifyingForwardingAppender()
        {
            Queue = new Queue<LoggingEvent>();
        }

        ~MessageModifyingForwardingAppender()
        {
            Flush();
        }

        protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
        {
            Queue.Enqueue(loggingEvent);
        }

        internal void Flush()
        {
            while (Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var l = Queue.Dequeue();
                // my logic...

                // and now I need to use the FileAppender, but with a different destination folder. How?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some ideas?

Comment: _"now I need to use the FileAppender, but with a different destination folder. How?"_ - If you want a second log file, use another file appender.

Comment: If log file is confusing, why not to print thread id like so [%thread] ?